# Aggregate LINQ function to take place of this "accumalator" function

Tags: c#, linq

So I have this function:

```
var ordersInLast7Days = lineItems
                            .Where(x => x.OrderLogged > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7))
                            .ToList();

ordersInLast7Days.ForEach(lineItem =>
{
    var qty = lineItem.Quantity;
    var pack = packs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id.Equals(lineItem.PackId));

    if (pack != null)
    {
        orderTotalsInLast7Days += qty * pack.Price;
    }
});
```

How would I make that into an `Aggregate` LINQ function that collects `qty * pack.Price`?

To elaborate somewhat, I have 3 of these functions that are all the same, so just guna have one method to apply to all `Aggregates`.

Comment: Love that this was downvoted, for `insert reason here`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with dasblinkenlight but to provide a solution using aggregate:

```
var total = lineItems.Where(x => x.OrderLogged > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7) && packs.Any(y => y.Id.Equals(x.PackId)))

.Aggregate(0, (res, item) => res += item.Quantity * packs.First(y => y.Id.Equals(item.PackId)).Price);
```

Comment: Accepted this, because it fits my needs more

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Sum` to accumulate the total of `qty * pack.Price`, like this:

```
orderTotalsInLast7Days = ordersInLast7Days
    .Select(lineItem => new {
        qty = lineItem.Quantity
    ,   pack = packs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id.Equals(lineItem.PackId))
    })
    .Where(p => p.pack != null)
    .Sum(p => p.qty * p.pack.Price);
```

This is a straightforward translation of your iterative code, which uses an anonymous type instead of local variables.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way:

```
orderTotalsInLast7Days =
(
    from lineItem in lineItems
    where lineItem.OrderLogged > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7)
    let qty = lineItem.Quantity
    from pack in packs.Where(x => x.Id.Equals(lineItem.PackId)).Take(1)
    select qty * pack.Price
).Sum();
```